# Get the highest number value 'Magento'

Tags: php, magento

I have this function and i want to get the highest number value.
$array is out-putting 20, 50, 40. 
I want to print 50 only not the other 2. 
Tried everything nothing is working.

```
foreach ($products as $product) {

    $originalPriceCat = $product->getPrice();
    $finalPriceCat = $product->getFinalPrice();

    if ($originalPriceCat > $finalPriceCat) {
        $CalculatedPrice = ($originalPriceCat - $finalPriceCat) * 100 /$originalPriceCat;
        $array = array($CalculatedPrice);
        echo round(max($array));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will surely solve your problem

```
$CalculatedPrice = array();
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $originalPriceCat = $product->getPrice();
    $finalPriceCat = $product->getFinalPrice();                                                    
    if ($originalPriceCat > $finalPriceCat) {
        $CalculatedPrice[] = ($originalPriceCat - $finalPriceCat) * 100 / $originalPriceCat;                                                                            
    }                                                       
} 
echo round(max($CalculatedPrice));
```

Comment: Amazing Raghubendra Singh Worked perfectly fine. another thing. when the value is empty its out putting 0 how to remove that.

Comment: Which value is empty?  Please elaborate...

Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: check if the value is 0 before printing/outputting it

Comment: Ok the code is basically in <ul <li>. so one of the categories that is in <li> has no discounted products so its printing 0. also tell me how to accept the answer as resolved.

Comment: In that case before printing the value you can check if it is empty by using isset or empty function. 

To accept this answer just click on the tick on the left side of my answer and when it turns green its done..

Comment: Done Thanks for the help. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this php function: [max](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php)

```
max ( array $values ) : mixed
max ( mixed $value1 [, mixed $... ] ) : mixed
```

> If the first and only parameter is an array, max() returns the highest
>   value in that array. If at least two parameters are provided, max()
>   returns the biggest of these values.

**max()** returns the parameter value considered "highest" according to standard comparisons.
If multiple values of different types evaluate as equal (e.g. 0 and 'abc') the first provided to the function will be returned.

If an empty array is passed, then `FALSE` will be returned and an `E_WARNING` error will be emitted.

Comment: echo round(max($CalculatedPrice));

Comment: can you give us the output of $CalculatedPrice

Comment: Hi @ThomasKühn , this answer is almost 4 years old and I'm sorry for being a "link-only" offender back then. I have edited my answer to include some info from the docs. Regards

Comment: @Minzkraut Your answer popped up in the review queue, don't know how this happens after such a long time. I removed my comment now.